# How to bind (set) existing values to mat select in Angular

Tags: angular

I have  a drop down for which i have used mat-select.
If it is a single or multi select it works fine, no issues while binding the existing values and etc..

My requirement is, I should be able to create and remove dynamic rows.
Now, each dynamic row will have two drop downs in each column.

So for this I have used a simple table structure with `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Here's the code:

```html
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let person of lienPositionData; let i = index">
  <td>
    <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-select formControlName="associatedLoan" name="associatedLoan"
                  [(ngModel)]="person.id">
        <div>
          <mat-option
                  *ngFor="let lnDDL of loanDropDownMultiSelect | searchDocs:{productName: searchLoan}"
                  [value]="lnDDL.id"
                  style="cursor: pointer; margin: 6px; height: 38px;font-size: 14px;">
            {{lnDDL.productName}}
          </mat-option>
        </div>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
  <td>
    <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" class="inline-block">
      <mat-select placeholder="Select" formControlName="lienPosition"
                  name="lienPosition"
                  [(ngModel)]="person.text">
        <mat-option></mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="table-remove">
      <button type="button" class="collateral-detail-button-remove"
              (click)="remove(i)"
              mat-flat-button>Remove</button>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

`lienPositionData` is something based on this, rows are generated and it contains the existing data to be binded to DDL.

For example, if `lienPositionData` has 2 records so there should be two rows. And this also has those unique records to be binded to two different DDL.

But now I am able to bind, but that is same for both DDL like ,

example:

```
lienPositionData[0] - id : 1 , name : test
lienPositionData[1] - id : 2 , name : test2
```

So test2 is getting binded to both the dropdowns.

See the image below:

[image: DDL with data binded twice, or last record has been binded]

I am unable to understand how to bind existing data. tried so much, but no luck till now.

Comment: Can you share a stackbiltz

Comment: ok. will share and update you shortly

Comment: Are you using `FormControl` ? You could just pass the `formControlName` and it will do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `[(ngModel)]` to set the existing value.

From your stackbiltz example,

**[Forked Stackbiltz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wiccq5-9jtg4w?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.html)**

.html

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let dt of data;let i = index">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
            <mat-select [(ngModel)]="data[i]">
                <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]='opt.id'>{{opt.name}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </tr>
</table>
```

.ts

```
data = ['op1', 'op2', 'op3']

options = [
  {id:'op1',name:"A"},
  {id:'op2',name:"B"},
  {id:'op3',name:"C"},
]
```

Comment: hi, this works fine. but i try to iterate mat-select inside a ngFor it breaks

Comment: Can you add your case in the demo and share the forked one

Comment: i ll share that piece of code at the bottom of the sample which i have shared above

Comment: will this do ? because i have tried the same it breaks

Comment: Comment your `data` values

Comment: ok. now it is neither generating nor binding. 
example, my DDL has 3 values : op1, op2, op3... out of which i have already saved op1 in DB. 
as only one value is saved so only one ROW will get generated, and that row contains DDL wth value binded as op1. and rest will be populated as if user wants to update

Comment: Check the modified demo if it helps

Comment: thanks, yeah it is working. will check this approach with the actual code. 
shall i get back to you for any further queries, if there.

Comment: Yeah sure. Do let me know

Comment: Did it help...?

Comment: No. Sorry for late reply.
no is still not binding.

<mat-option value='op1'>Option 1</mat-option>
             <mat-option value="op2">Option 2</mat-option>
             <mat-option value="op3">Option 3</mat-option>

what should be value = "" ?

i guess due to this it is not working for me.

Comment: i have the object , 
lienPositionData with properties : id and  name is something i want to bind .

so instead of value="op1" what i should put to get it bind ?

since i tried value = "lienpositiondata" and few more trail and error, but it is the same.

Comment: Check the modified answer if you want this, you should have cleared all the requirements in the question itself

Comment: Will surely check, I am sorry for that. i tried to clear everything in my question, but sorry as it didn't clarify you.